# Server connection

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

My friend cant connect to his multiplayer forge server at all not even with localhost and stuff
his error message is this:
`io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information:`
and the server launcher code is: `java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2838-universal.jar -o true nogui`
and when i try to join his server with right ip and everything it says:`io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information:`
so is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what service provider you're using. I'll just assume you're using aternos. If you go to your home screen, go back to vanilla and delete your mods file. All the world will delete so before you do that make a backup of the world. After you change to vanilla you load the backup. There are tutorials on the aternos website that show you how to get mods or plugins on your server, although they're known to be buggy with aternos as it is a free service. You can also use the aternos forums for tutorials on how to get mods on your server. Keeping it on vanilla should mean that your friend can join as Forge can be very buggy with aternos as I have experienced this problem too.